# MASM32 Editor - project crashing

Tags: arrays, assembly, crash, masm32

I'm working on an assembly project, where I need to convert a 'Date-formatted' array, to a number representative array, then bubble sort the number array, then convert the array back to Date-format.

I'm currently JUST trying to test my bubble sort macro with a test number array, and see if it can sort them from least to greatest. I'm not getting any compile errors, but when I run the generated .exe file, the CMD crashes and I have no clue why..
Any help would be appreciated.

This is the current code I'm compiling:

```
.486 ; create 32 bit code
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
include \masm32\macros\macros.asm

includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

.data
    dates BYTE "23-JUL-2010", 0, "23-JAN-2010", 0, "23-JUL-2009", 0, "31-JUL-2012", 0, "05-MAR-2010", 0
    testArray DWORD 5 DUP(7, 5, 9, 1, 0)
    nDates DWORD 5

.code
; ------------- Macros -------------

; Convert Date formatted string (DD-MMM-YYYY) to Number
;DateToNumber MACRO date, number
    ; TODO
;ENDM

; Convert Number to Date formatted string
;NumberToDate MACRO number, date
    ; TODO
;ENDM

; Bubble sort an array of integers
BubbleSort MACRO array, length
    LOCAL outer
    LOCAL inner
    LOCAL compare
    LOCAL swap
    LOCAL done

    mov esi, -1

outer:
    inc esi
    mov edi, -1
    cmp esi, length
    je done

inner:
    inc edi
    cmp edi, length - 1
    je outer

compare:
    mov eax, [array + edi * 4h]
    mov ebx, [array + edi * 4h + 4]
    cmp eax, ebx
    jle inner

swap:
    mov [array + edi * 4h], ebx
    mov [array + edi * 4h + 4], eax
    jmp inner

done:

ENDM

start:

    lea EAX, dates      ; create pointer to beginning of dates array
    mov ECX, nDates     ; set up loop counter

    BubbleSort testArray, nDates
    sub edi, edi
    mov edi, -1
printNum_loop:
    inc edi
    sub esi, esi
    mov esi, [testArray + (4h * edi)]
    print str$(esi)
    print chr$(" ")
    cmp edi, 9
    jl printNum_loop

    print chr$(13,10)
    print chr$(13,10)

loop_top:
    push EAX            ; save EAX and ECX because print macros change these
    push ECX
    print EAX           ; print date at pointer location
    print chr$(13,10)
    pop ECX
    pop EAX

    add EAX, 12         ; increment pointer, note that date has 12
                        ; bytes including null-terminator
    loop loop_top       ; continue loop

    inkey   ;Keep the window open
    exit

end start
```

I apologize if it's something extremely obvious.. I'm new to assemble/MASM32..

Comment: Use a debugger to see where it crashes. That said, `length - 1` is extremely suspicious. I doubt that does what you think it does.

Comment: Macro syntax is rather touchy in MASM32. Generally, it is designed for very small pieces of simple code. It's syntax is close to regular MASM32 syntax, but not quite identical. For the purpose of bubble sorting, a traditional proc (procedure) may work better than a macro. Each invocation of a macro inserts the entirety of the macro code *each time it is used*.  Two uses = two bubble sort routines, both used once. A proc is a standard function call; so 100 calls to it = just one bubble sort code, used 100 times.

Comment: Indeed, `cmp edi, length - 1` is probably being expanded to `cmp edi, [nDates - 1]`, which probably isn't what you intended.

Comment: Should `nDates DWORD 5` be `nDates EQU 5`?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I did end up switching to a procedure instead of a MACRO, and it ended up fixing the issue.. I am using MASM32 editor (Which is what we're told to use by our teacher) and it doesn't really have any debugging capabilities... That's why I asked. So I'm still not really positive why the above code was crashing.